# adding & in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm getting the 404 error due to a missing special character "&" in the url. hence i want to change the url from

http://www.example.com/option=com_rplview=propertyshowpid=5127

to

http://www.example.com/option=com_rpl&view=propertyshow&pid=5127

How can i do using .htaccess

THanks,
R

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the ? from the query string in addition to &. Assuming that you just want to match this exact URL (pid=5127) -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (option=com_rpl)(view=propertyshow)(pid=5127) /?$1&$2&$3 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to match on any `pid` value 1 to 4 digits long

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (option=com_rpl)(view=propertyshow)(pid=\d{1,4}) /?$1&$2&$3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Url encodes the amersand (&) to `%26` is the correct way to do this.`replace & by %26`